# How to reference multiple levels up/down in normalised nosql database?

Tags: database, nosql, graphql, data-modeling, database-normalization

I'm trying to model a database which can use the flexibility of graphql, but want to make it normalised.

Imagine this relational structure:

```
planet
  continent
    country
      city
```

But I'd like to create four different collections to keep it normalised.

To best describe, a schema for it would look like:

```
type Planet {
  planetName: String
}
type Continent {
  continentName: String
}
type Country {
  countryName: String
}
type City {
  cityName: String
}

type Query {
  planets: [Planet]
  continents: [Continent]
  countries: [Country]
  cities: [City]
}
```

Great, I can query for each individual elements, and get all of them.

But what if I would like to get for example all the cities of a continent?

I'd need to refine the next pieces:

```
type Continent {
  continentName: String
  cities: [City]
}
type City {
  cityName: String
}
type Query {
  planets: [Planet]
  continents: [Continent]
  countries: [Country]
  cities: [City]
}
```

Now if we query, we'll get the `continentName` (the id), and we could get all the cities belonging to it. But we'll need to make some sort of relation between a city and a continent. My idea was something like to do in the database structure:

```
continent: {
  continentName, //the id
  countries, //array of ids of countries
  cities //array of ids of cities
}
```

This way I can write a resolver to get the `cities` from the parent object of the query, and query from the cities collection of the specified ids.

But what if I would like to do something like this:

```
type Query {
  cities(continentName: String): [City]
}
```

So going the other way around, get all the cities belonging to the continent. I could go, and query the specific continent, get all cities belonging to it, and fetch the specified cities, but it would take long.

What if I would structure data like this:

```
continent: {
  continentName, //the id
  planetName //id of the belonging planet
},
city: {
  cityName, //the id
  countryName, // id of the belonging country
  continentName, //id of the belonging continent
  planetName //id of the belonging planet
}
```

With the above structure I'm able to connect, and query data in nested format no matter from what level how much levels down, and which direction. It seems as the perfect solution, but as I've read modelling noSQL databases, I haven't found it nowhere.

Any possible bottlenecks or issues with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is difficult.

I think the best approach is to split the problem into multiple smaller problems:

- Create a collection that describe the regions of the world, regions will be associated with geometric shapes of WGS84 coordinates (or planet specific coordinate system)
- Create a collection of `PointOfInterest` like cities, those will be just WGS84 coordinates (somewhat like longitute and latitude).

Then you need a way to query for intersection, inclusion and union of geometric shapes.

You will also need to be able to tell if a point is in a shape and what points are in a given shape.

There will be some dynamic programming involved because there is, as far as I know, no coordinate system that works across the universe.

Look into PostGIS, GDAL and https://github.com/sshuair/awesome-gis

Good luck :)